# Centering images with text as menu

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put together some images together with an text under the images which will work as an menu, which should be centered horizontal under an header. The website is supposed to work as an responsive website. The HTML and CSS code is currently looking like this:

*Edited*

I want 5 images, each one of them shall have a text under them. And I want the my images together with the text to be centered.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
<div id="content">
<img src="ikoner/icon_90_2.png"/>
<div class="text"><a href="#">Utvecklingen sedan 90-talet</a></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<img src="ikoner/icon_html5.png"/>
<div class="text"><a href="#">HTML5</a></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<img src="ikoner/icon_html5video.png"/>
<div class="text"><a href="#">HTML5 Video</a></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
>img src="ikoner/icon_responsive.png"/>
<div class="text"><a href="#">Responsive Webdesign</a></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<img src="ikoner/icon_heart.png"/>
<div class="text"><a href="#">Emotional Design</a></div>
</div>    
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
position: relative;
width: 15%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}

#content img    {
padding-top: 370px;
width: 100px;
}

.text   {
font-size: 12px;
font-family: 'ciclethin';
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: And your question/problem is...?

Comment: Are you trying to center just the text under each image? If so you should set .text to margin:0 auto;

Your question isn't really stating what it is you need help with.

Comment: The text is centered under the image. Im trying to center all the images and the text together. But I can't figure it out, it's always floating to the left. Have tried:
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

But it doesn't work

Comment: what dimension of images?

Answer (score 0):

You're not aligning your "Nav" div anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've changed the id="content" to classes, because IDs should be unique to the page.
Set nav element to text-align:center. Here's a fiddle, and the relevant code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cw16tkdn/2/

```
<nav>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
        <div class="text"><a href="#">Utvecklingen sedan 90-talet</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
        <div class="text"><a href="#">HTML5</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
        <div class="text"><a href="#">HTML5 Video</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
        <div class="text"><a href="#">Responsive Webdesign</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
        <div class="text"><a href="#">Emotional Design</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and CSS:

```
nav {
    text-align:center;
}
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.content img {
    width: 100px;
}
.text {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:'ciclethin';
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want this:  (i have changed id=content with class=content in html code!)

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 520px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:bottom; 

}

.content img    {
    padding-top: 370px;
    width: 100px;
    display:block;
    margin: auto;
}

.text a   {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'ciclethin';
    text-decoration: none;
}

.text {
    height: 3em; 

}
```